# SQl 2012 dead lock process by SA

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, database-deadlocks

Have a SQL Server 2012 with a SCCM database.

Problem I'm having is we have index errors.

Trying to run

```
DBCC CHECKDB (CM_KRW, REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)
```

But getting errors so I had to switch to single user.

Then I ran the command again and it finally worked after several other error messages saying multiple users were connected to the DB.

Now I need to change the DB back to Multi User:

Using:

```
ALTER DATABASE CM_KRW
SET MULTI_USER
```

But am seeing the error

> Msg 1205, Level 13, State 68, Line 2
>   Transaction (Process ID 53) was deadlocked on lock resources with another    process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
>
> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

I ran a SQL Server Profiler trace log for deadlocks and i see lots of them all comming from SA account, for which i dont have the password and account is set to deny login.

Any ideas what I can do now?

Comment: What seeing in the trace:

Comment: You need to have a word with your DBA to sort this. I'm assuming you have a DBA if you don't have access yourself to the sa password

Comment: yes. see thats the problem. Our DBA decided to set it all up then leave for another project. And now when we ask he never has any time as its not in his scope anymore. Though i could do this with my account but seems i need the SA. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: Then you need to raise to the next level if you can't resolve this. He can't expect you to fix this with handcuffs on (no sa password)